# Adapt code to work with dynamic number and name of dataframe columns instead of static ones

Tags: r

I have the data frame below:

```
rp<-structure(list(ProductFamily = c("PF_1", "PF_10", "PF_10", "PF_100", 
"PF_100", "PF_101", "PF_102", "PF_102", "PF_102", "PF_102", "PF_103", 
"PF_103", "PF_104", "PF_105", "PF_106", "PF_106", "PF_106", "PF_106", 
"PF_107", "PF_108", "PF_109", "PF_11", "PF_110", "PF_110", "PF_111"
), TreatmenArea = c("TA_7", "TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_6", "TA_6", "TA_2", 
"TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_2", 
"TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_7", 
"TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_7"), Subarea = c("SA_16", "SA_5", "SA_5", 
"SA_15", "SA_15", "SA_6", "SA_6", "SA_6", "SA_6", "SA_6", "SA_6", 
"SA_6", "SA_6", "SA_6", "SA_6", "SA_6", "SA_6", "SA_6", "SA_6", 
"SA_6", "SA_6", "SA_17", "SA_6", "SA_6", "SA_22"), Ind = c("volume_1", 
"volume_5", "volume_6", "volume_52", "volume_3", "volume_16", 
"volume_16", "volume_12", "volume_3", "volume_11", "volume_20", 
"volume_3", "volume_12", "volume_12", "volume_79", "volume_52", 
"volume_1", "volume_24", "volume_16", "volume_16", "volume_16", 
"volume_7", "volume_80", "volume_1", "volume_16"), Country_1 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 92.6961421759861, NA, NA, NA, NA, 78.3001808318264, 
NA, NA, NA, 106.832963501416, 0.613496932515337, 104.21011973735, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 99.5238622522423, NA, NA), Country_2 = c(NA, 
NA, 161.55950752394, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 59.1346153846154, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 128.113063407181, 93.3812839543959, NA, NA, NA, 137.724550898204, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 90.1602849510241, 37.3939722071828)), row.names = c(NA, 
25L), class = "data.frame")
```

and I want to replace the `NAs` with the values of a second dataframe `rp2` (if exist) by same `Country_` and `Subarea`. For example if we see that `Country_1` for `Subarea SA16` is `NA` in `rp` we go to `rp2` and replace it with `108.35096`

```
rp2<-structure(list(TreatmenArea = c("TA_1", "TA_1", "TA_1", "TA_1", 
"TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_3", "TA_4", "TA_4", "TA_5", "TA_5", 
"TA_5", "TA_6", "TA_6", "TA_7", "TA_7", "TA_7", "TA_7", "TA_7", 
"TA_7", "TA_7", "TA_7", "TA_8", "TA_9"), Subarea = c("SA_1", 
"SA_2", "SA_3", "SA_4", "SA_5", "SA_6", "SA_7", "SA_8", "SA_10", 
"SA_9", "SA_11", "SA_12", "SA_13", "SA_14", "SA_15", "SA_16", 
"SA_17", "SA_18", "SA_19", "SA_20", "SA_21", "SA_22", "SA_23", 
"SA_24", "SA_25"), Country_1 = c(101.37519256645, 105.268942332558, 
100.49933368058, 104.531597221684, NA, 83.4404308144341, 86.2833044714836, 
81.808967345926, 79.6786979951661, 77.6863475527052, NA, 78.3001808318264, 
112.499238782021, 113.526674294436, NA, 108.350959378962, NA, 
NA, 102.243471199266, NA, 104.323270355678, NA, NA, NA, 100), 
    Country_2 = c(98.7267717862572, 83.9572019653478, 97.164068306148, 
    103.654771613923, 161.55950752394, 75.4091957339533, 96.5255996196344, 
    99.8317785594128, 88.1477193135348, NA, NA, NA, 151.411687458963, 
    107.652477161141, NA, NA, NA, NA, 92.4695215620261, NA, 88.9890571623243, 
    39.1847909816402, 87.0642912470953, NA, NA)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -25L), groups = structure(list(
    TreatmenArea = c("TA_1", "TA_2", "TA_3", "TA_4", "TA_5", 
    "TA_6", "TA_7", "TA_8", "TA_9"), .rows = structure(list(1:4, 
        5:7, 8L, 9:10, 11:13, 14:15, 16:23, 24L, 25L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -9L), .drop = TRUE))
```

I achieve it with:

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(rp, rp2, by = "Subarea", suffix = c("", ".y")) %>%
  mutate(Country_1 = coalesce(Country_1, Country_1.y),
         Country_2 = coalesce(Country_2, Country_2.y)) %>%
  select(!ends_with(".y"))
```

But my actual dataset is going to be dynamic and instead of `Country_1,Country_2` etc is going to have a numerous number of countries like `England,France` etc. so I want to adapt the code above to read the dataset names whatever they be instead of `Country_1` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By bringing the data (i.e. `rp` and `rp2`) into long form (with respect to the countries) we can avoid having to specify the countries individually. But since there are multiple entries in `rp` for the same value in `Subarea` we have to create a unique ID (`rowID`) first, so that we can bring the data into the original form at the end.

I am assuming that `rp2` has only one row per unique value for `Subarea` (as in the example you provided).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
rp %>% 
  mutate(rowID = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(col = -c(rowID, ProductFamily, TreatmenArea, Subarea, Ind ), names_to = "Country", values_to = "Value_1") %>% 
  left_join(rp2 %>% pivot_longer(col = -c(TreatmenArea, Subarea), names_to = "Country", values_to = "Value_2")) %>% 
  mutate(value = coalesce(Value_1, Value_2)) %>% 
  select(-Value_1, -Value_2) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Country, values_from = value) %>% 
  select(-rowID)
```

Comment: your code works but I have tried it with all the other columns I have in my dataframe and it does not so I edited my Q including all columns I need to be included in the final output

Comment: @firmo23 See my updatet answer. If the data is unique per `ProductFamily` - `TreatmenArea` - `Subarea` - `Ind` combination (as it is in the new example) we can avoid the rowID thing (just remove the first mutate line and the last select line and any reference to the variable).

Comment: How do you specify here that the replacements happen based on Subarea only? Cause this is what matters. I just want the rest of the columns to be displayed in the final output

Comment: `rp2` is joined using `TreatmenArea` and `Subarea` (which doesn't matter for the example data since `Subarea` is unique in `rp2`) and `Country`. Or in other words: For each country Value_2 represents the value for that `Subarea`(+`TreatmenArea`).  It's speciefied by the left_join (well actually, its implicitly specified by the common variables between the long form of rp and rp2. We could make it explicit by adding `by = c("TreatmenArea" = "TreatmenArea", "Subarea" = "Subarea", "Country" = "Country")` to the call to `left_join`). Does that answer your question?

Comment: since it works as expected yes .Im going to check it